# Can I check if a pointer has been assigned to something other than malloc?

Tags: c, pointers, null, malloc, string

After setting a `char *` pointer to `malloc(size)`, is there a way to check if it's still not been changed? I thought that a pointer to unassigned space would evaluate to `NULL` but apparently not:

```
char *string = malloc(500);
if(string==NULL) puts("Hello World");
else puts("It's not null");
```

I think this should output `"Hello World"` but it doesn't. How can I check if string has been changed by something like `strcpy()` or `strcat()` or, even more relevantly to my own project, by:

```
fgets(string, 499, fr)
```

Comment: For your project, check the return value of `fgets`. It'll be `NULL` if `fgets` failed.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be a bit confused about what `malloc()` does and about the role of NULL.

The `malloc()` function allocates space, but does not initialize the space to any value.  The return value from `malloc()` is a pointer to (the first byte of) that space.  Unless you attempt to allocate zero bytes<sup>1</sup>, the return value from `malloc()` will only be NULL if it was unable to allocate as much space as you asked for<sup>2</sup>.

Therefore, your program will not print "Hello World" unless your system is running extremely short of memory.  The pointer `string` will be a valid memory location.

What is completely undefined is the data that `string` points at.  You would have to initialize it somehow, for example, with:

```
strcpy(string, "Hello World");
```

Now you could safely do:

```
printf("%s!\n", string);
```

Before you initialize it, it is not 'safe' to read the memory; there is no guarantee about what you'll find in it.  Your program won't crash, but what you see is what you get.

You can also safely use:

```
if (fgets(string, 500, stdin) != 0)
    printf("Read: %s", string);
```

Note that `fgets()` reserves a space for the terminal `'\0'`; you don't have to shrink the space by one.

---

You ask:

> How can I check if `string` has been changed by something like `strcpy()` or `strcat()` or ...

For most practical purposes, you can't determine if it has been modified because there is no defined content for the memory.  If you really wanted to know, you could probably do:

```
char *string_copy = malloc(500);
if (string_copy != NULL)
    memmove(string_copy, string, 500);
```

to make a copy of the original content of the memory that was allocated, and then use:

```
if (memcmp(string_copy, string, 500) != 0)
   ...someone changed either string or string_copy (or both)...
```

It is rather thin ice; the value in the allocated space is not defined, but in practice, I'd be surprised to find it doesn't work.  On the other hand, I can't think of a circumstance where I'd be interested in this knowledge.  If I allocate memory, it is in order to use it — usually almost immediately.

---

<sup>1</sup> If you allocate zero bytes, you get one of two implementation-defined behaviours.  Either you get a NULL pointer returned, or you get a valid, non-NULL pointer to zero bytes of accessible memory (so you can't safely access) that is distinct from any other memory allocation.  The result, either way, can be safely passed to `free()`.  If you allocate zero bytes, any attempt to access memory via the pointer returned leads to undefined behaviour.

<sup>2</sup> Beware that on Linux, you can ask for massive amounts of memory and `malloc()` will claim to allocate it for you, but you may find that when you come to access it, it is not available after all.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot in a reliable, cross-platform way. Why don't you initialize the memory returned by `malloc()` to all zeros? Then you could see if it's been changed.

In your example, you're testing the value of the pointer itself, which will point to the memory allocated. That can't be null unless `malloc()` failed.

Comment: How about if i changed the pointers to char arrays?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you mean, but don't see how that would help. Why not just initialize the memory using `memset()` or even just `string[0] = '\0'`? You can then assume it has not been changed while `strlen(string) == 0`.

Comment: If the code executes `string[1] = 1;`, the memory has changed, but `strlen(string) == 0` is still true.  You're right that if you've initialized the memory to a known value, you can spot changes in it, but your test only works if the first byte of the allocated memory is modified to a non-zero value (and could run into problems if all 500 bytes were set to non-zero because the 'string' is no longer null-terminated).

Comment: Sure. I suggested using `memset()` and writing code to see if the data has changed. But it occurred to me that it might be enough to just know if it contains a valid string and so I offered that as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

`After setting a char * pointer to malloc(size), is there a way to check if it's still not been changed?`

- Yes,  pretty much what you're doing, but you'll need to start the pointer off to `NULL`. Then you'll know if it was changed from `NULL` or not with your code.

`I thought that a pointer to unassigned space would evaluate to NULL`

No, a pointer evaluates to `NULL` when you set it to `NULL`:

```
char *string = NULL;
if(string==NULL) puts("Hello World"); //Will execute this
else puts("It's not null");

string = malloc(500);  //Assuming this was successful

if(string==NULL) puts("Hello World");
else puts("It's not null");  //Now we'll execute this
```

`I think this should output "Hello World" but it doesn't`

- Right, because it's not `NULL` it's a valid pointer value (assuming the `malloc()` was successful)

`How can I check if string has been changed by something like strcpy() or strcat() or fgets()`

- You can't check this from the pointer value, you need to keep track of when your string changed yourself. [fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) returns `NULL` in case of a failure, so your string wasn't changed if that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Who said this, `I thought that a pointer to unassigned space would evaluate to NULL but apparently not`?

After `char *string = malloc(500);`

`string` is pointing to the first byte of that allocated space or `heap` (unless allocation somehow failed) 
hence your `string` pointer is not `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a pointer as an integer variable, whose value is a memory address, So if a pointer is null this means that the actual value of the variable is the non-existent address null (denoted by the value 0).

When you write something like `char *p = (char *)malloc(100);` what you are asking is for the compiler to find an unused space of 100 bytes and set the value of p to the address of the first byte in that space. Now the variable has a value and it is not Null.

Now in light of that the variable p itself has **nothing** to do with whether any memory slot after this address (`p*` in C terms) changes or not.